# Remove faint imprint of stickers from space grey macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

Removed some stickers from the lid of my space grey 2017 MBP. Managed to remove the sticky residue using some rubbing alcohol but there is still some discolouration where the stickers were. Any tips on solving this or is the discolouration permanent?[image]

Comment: You should put a sticker on it asking people to guess what you removed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The space grey coating is [anodized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anodizing) and possibly dyed.

What your photo illustrates is differential weathering effects upon the aluminum surface. Where the stickers were is the original color - you actually are asking how to reverse the weathering or basically re-anodize or dye the layer of chemically modified aluminum alloy so that the exposed portions match the unchanged. An equivalent process would be to  somehow catch up the protected portions to match perfectly to the rest of the Mac.

Basically, you’re not likely to “fix” this just like tattoo removal in some cases isn’t able to restore the unpigmented condition of some skin types and ink combinations.

Back to the Mac - once you’ve used a solvent to remove the residue of any adhesive or remnants of vinyl or whatever other material you introduced, the actual oxidized layer may be permanently changed.

Comment: The good news is with use, you’ll likely oxidize both areas and they will become less noticeable or perhaps this will come into style - echoes of a past sticker ridden life and now your mac is middle-aged with age-appropriate scars and patina.

Comment: I experienced the same. Never had this issue with stickers on any of my many silver MacBooks, so seems to be specific to the space grey finish.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Goof Off on a couple of MacBooks that the kids have put stickers all over. You can find it in pretty much any retail store like Home Depot, Walmart or even from Amazon.

Had good results and never damaged the finish of the laptops or the iPods.